# ggplot2 legend text color

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have an issue with coloring a text of a legend (each group name with corresponding colour) in ggplot2. This is my desired output:

[image]

I am using this data:

```
df <- data.frame(group = c("Group 1","Group 2","Group 3")
                 , value = c(1000000, 300000, 100000)
                 , value_format = c("1.000.000", "300.000", "100.000")
                 , weigth = c("71,4%", "21,4%", "7,14%")
                 , stringsAsFactors = F)

lables <- paste(paste(df$group, df$value_format, sep = ": "), df$weigth, sep = "\n")
```

And this is the code with my better aproximation:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(extrafont)

g <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x = 1, y = value, fill = factor(group)))
g <- g + geom_bar(position="stack",stat="identity")
g <- g + theme(
  plot.margin = unit(c(0, 0, 0, 0), "in")
  , axis.line = element_blank()
  , axis.text.x = element_blank()
  , axis.text.y = element_blank()
               , axis.ticks = element_blank()
               , axis.title.x = element_blank()
               , axis.title.y = element_blank()
               , panel.background = element_blank()
               , panel.border = element_blank()
               , panel.grid.major = element_blank()
               , panel.grid.minor = element_blank()
               , plot.background = element_blank()
               , legend.position="top"
               , legend.title = element_blank()
               , legend.text.align = .5
               , legend.text = element_text(colour = c("#595959", "#E26B0A", "#00B0F0")
                                            , family = "Arial"
                                            , size = 11, face = "bold")
               , legend.key.size = unit(0.5, "cm")
               )
g <- g + scale_fill_manual(values=c("#595959", "#E26B0A", "#00B0F0"), 
                       breaks=c("Group 1","Group 2","Group 3"),
                       labels=lables)
g <- g + coord_flip()
g
```

From this point I am not able to make 3 things:

1. Color the text corresponding to each group (note that I introduce a vector of colors inside the `element_text` for `legend.text` but it takes the first value only
2. Remove the legend.key (boxes with colors)
3. Distribute a legend text over the bar

Appreciate any help

Comment: It might be easier to forget about the legend and use [annotate](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3/annotate.html).

Comment: @Axeman, I am new to ggplot so need to check it out! But seems to be a good idea

Comment: If you're having trouble annotating outside the plotting area, have a look at the `cowplot` package, which gives more versatility.

Comment: @Axeman, thank you for your comments! I will take a look. It seems that `annotate` will do a job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved the problem using `annotate` function, as @Axeman suggested below. This is my final code (with some adjustment's tricks):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(extrafont)
g <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = 1, y = value, fill = factor(group))) +
  geom_bar(position = "stack", stat = "identity") + 
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(.5, 0.2, 0, 0.1), "in")
        , axis.line = element_blank()  
        , axis.text.x = element_blank()  
        , axis.text.y = element_blank()  
        , axis.ticks = element_blank() 
        , axis.title.x = element_blank() 
        , axis.title.y = element_blank()  
        , panel.background = element_blank()  
        , panel.border = element_blank()  
        , panel.grid.major = element_blank()  
        , panel.grid.minor = element_blank()  
        , plot.background = element_blank()  
        , legend.position=""          
        ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#595959", "#E26B0A", "#00B0F0"), 
                    breaks=c("Group 1","Group 2","Group 3"),
                    labels=lables) +
  coord_flip() +
  annotate("text", label=lables[1], x=1.8, y = df$value[1]/2           
                , fontface = "bold", color = "#595959", family="Arial", size = 4.5) +  
  annotate("text", label=lables[2], x=1.8, y = sum(df$value)-400000           
           , fontface = "bold", color = "#E26B0A", family="Arial", size = 4.5) +  
  annotate("text", label=lables[3], x=1.8, y = sum(df$value)-100000           
           , fontface = "bold", color = "#00B0F0", family="Arial", size = 4.5) 

g
```

Thank's!