# Can I manipulate the legend in ggplot by removing the icons and change the color of the text instead?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
data(iris)
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_point(aes(color=Species))
```

The legend for the graph shows the 3 colored dots next to the 3 types of species. I was wondering if I could remove the dot icons next to the text in the legend and instead give the text the corresponding color instead. So the "setosa" text in the legend would be colored the red color, "versicolor" the green color, and "virginica" the blue color.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43669587/9511702) could be helpfull

Comment: Or use [`annotate`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48526081/786542)